# Issues with fixed HTML header using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-tables

I'm working with HTML tables and I have the need to make the header "stuck" to the top. I'm using **jQuery** to achieve that and I'm pretty satisfied with the result till now, except some issues I'm facing.

I'll try to explain well what I'd like to achieve with my code and I also created a fiddle to better explain my request: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc0rE/tom1qspq/1/

To facilitate the reading of this question, below I copied the JS code of my little project.

Here we have the JS:

```
// Take the widths of the header
var headerWidths = [];

var headerRow = $('thead').children('tr').children('th');
$(headerRow).each(function() {
  headerWidths.push($(this).width());
});

// Create new div containing the header
$(".headerContainer").css("position", "absolute");
$('thead').clone().appendTo('.headerContainer table').removeClass("headerRow");
$(".headerRow").css("visibility", "hidden");

// Resizing the columns
$('.headerContainer thead th').each(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();

  $(this).attr("id", "header" + i);
  $('#header' + i).css("width", headerWidths[i]);
});

// Scroll event and repositioning
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.headerContainer').css('transform', 'translate(0px,' + scrollY + 'px )');
});
```

And the CSS:

```css
table {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-weight: 200;
  background: white;
}

th,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 3px;
}

thead {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.mainContainer {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.headerContainer {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-weight: 200;
}

.headerContainer thead tr th {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

**ISSUES**

1. The Header (`.headerContainer`) is translating correctly, but I don't want the table content to appear behind the header while it is scrolling... (why is that happening?)
2. If I set the `.mainContainer` width and height to a fixed size (i.e 500px / 500px), my header is not translating correctly (I think he hates me..)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Take the widths of the header
var headerWidths = [];

var headerRow = $('thead').children('tr').children('th');
$(headerRow).each(function() {
  headerWidths.push($(this).width());
});

// Create new div containing the header
$(".headerContainer").css("position", "absolute");
$('thead').clone().appendTo('.headerContainer table').removeClass("headerRow");
$(".headerRow").css("visibility", "hidden");

// Resizing the columns
$('.headerContainer thead th').each(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();

  $(this).attr("id", "header" + i);
  $('#header' + i).css("width", headerWidths[i]);
});

// Scroll event and repositioning
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.headerContainer').css('transform', 'translate(0px,' + scrollY + 'px )');
});
/// you should to use that code IF (500:500)
// Scroll event and repositioning
//$(".mainContainer").scroll(function(event) {
//  var scrollY = $(".mainContainer").scrollTop();
//  $('.headerContainer').css('transform', 'translate(0px,' + scrollY + 'px )');
//});
```

1. You have `$(".headerContainer").css("position", "absolute");` Read more about this in docs.